# Prove any subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

was just wondering if this is a valid proof for the aforementioned question? I am quite confident that it isn't, but not exactly sure why. Maybe I am missing the point of proofs by induction (amateur...).

Let $G$ be a cyclic group generated by $g$ and $H$ a subgroup of it. Since $H$ is a subgroup, $1_G\in H$ thus the trivial subgroup is cyclic. Proceeding by induction: $H=\lbrace g^i:0\leq i<k, \rbrace$ is true for case $k=1$.

So assume true for $n=k$ thus $H=\lbrace g^i:0\leq i<k \rbrace$ and $H\cup \lbrace g^{k}\rbrace=\lbrace g^i:0\leq i<k \rbrace \cup \lbrace g^{k}\rbrace=\lbrace g^i:0\leq i<k+1 \rbrace$ so since it is true for $n=k+1$ we have that it is true for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Hopefully someone can point out the flaw, thanks.

Comment: What is $g$? $\,\,$

Comment: Presumably the element which generates the cyclic group.

Comment: I don't think you can use an induction argument in this proof. See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Cyclic_Group_is_Cyclic

Comment: $g$ is a generator of G, edited it now.

Comment: Here is one point where your attempted proof isn't working: Assume my group $G$ consists of $\{1_{G}, g, g^{2}, \ldots g^{n-1}\}$. Then you seem to be claiming that the subsets $\{1_{G}, g\}$, $\{1_{G},g,g^{2}\}$, etc. are all subgroups. But that's definitely not the case!

For example, think about $G = \mathbb{Z}_{10} = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Then you could choose $1$ as the generator of $G$, but the subgroups are things like $\{0,5\}$, $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$.

Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ look like "every other element" or "every third element", etc.; not "the first 5 elements".

Comment: Ah yeh, thanks! So I have essentially created cyclic subsets, which has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 7):

I would abandon induction as it does not help you for the infinite case. Let $g$ be the generator of $G$. Suppose $H$ is not cyclic. Then there exists $j$ and $k$ relatively prime where $g^j$ and $g^k$ are in $H$. But since $j$ and $k$ are relatively prime there exists $a,b$ such that $aj+bk = 1$. Hence $(g^j)^a+(g^k)^b = g$, so $g$ is in $H$. Hence $H=G$ which is cyclic, contradiction.

Comment: " Then there exists j and k relatively prime where g^j and g^k are in H." Proof?

Comment: If j and k are not relatively prime then g^j and g^k are both generated by g^x where x is the GCD of j and k. We can construct g^x the same way I do in my answer. If the group is not cyclic there are two elements in distinct orbits, but we have seen that if j and k are not relatively prime they are in the same orbit.

Comment: (I just thought the proof was in order.)

Comment: Fair enough, I did gloss over that point. OP do you like this answer? Any questions?

Comment: How did you get from $aj+bk = 1$ to $(g^j)^a+(g^k)^b = g$?

Comment: Yeah my notation is a bit confusing, since there is only one operation which is the group product. More appropriate would be ((g^j)^a)*((g^k)^b)) = g^(aj+bk) = g^1 = g. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes thanks, this is a very neat way of showing it, but does it hold for both the infinite and finite case?

Comment: Of course, why wouldn't it?

Comment: I never invoke the order of the group in my argument. It does not depend on the size of the group.

Comment: Cool, thanks. This is easier to understand than the one in my notes and is definitely one that I can work through myself.

Comment: Great! Glad you like my argument.

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it- could you explain the part about hcf(j,k)=1 again? Specifically I mean what happens if hcf(j,k)=n>1, I understand that they would be generated by g^n, but does that imply H would be cyclic (therefore hcf(j,k) has to be 1 since we assumed H non-cyclic)?

Comment: Here is a better way to think of it. Let x be the smallest natural number such that g^x is in H. I claim that if H is not cyclic there exists y, relatively prime to x, such that g^y is in H.

Comment: The proof is that if x and y have a common factor for every y, there exists z < x such that g^z is in H, which is a contradiction.

Comment: This is a brilliant proof

Answer (score 4):

Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ every element of $H$ can be expressed as $g^r$ for some $r\in \mathbb Z$. One possibility is that $H$ is trivial, hence cyclic. Else Let $m$ be the least positive value of $r$. Then $H$ is the cyclic group generated by $g^m$. Else there is an element $g^n\in H$ with $n=km+l$ and $1\leq l \lt m$, whence $g^l\in H$, which is a contradiction.

Least positive is justified by $g^r\in H \implies g^{-r}\in H$ - excluding the trivial group.

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathbb{Z}$, use division algorithm to show that any subgroup $H\le \mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $\langle n \rangle$ where $n$ is the smallest positive element of $H$.

Let $G$ be a cyclic group with generator $a$, then define a group homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\to G$ where $1\mapsto a$. This map is surjective since $\langle a\rangle = G$. Therefore $G\cong \mathbb{Z}/\ker f$. But $\ker f$ being a subgroup of $G$ is in the form $\langle n\rangle$, and we conclude that $G\cong \mathbb{Z}/\langle n\rangle$. If $n = 0$, then $G\cong \mathbb{Z}$. If $n = 1$, then $G\cong 0$. If $n$ is anything else, then $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_n$. These are up to isomorphism only possible cyclic groups.

For $\mathbb{Z}_n$, use Lagrange's theorem. Its possible subgroups are $\langle d\rangle \cong\mathbb{Z}_{n/d}$ where $d|n$.

Comment: Well, how do you show "cyclic groups are either $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z_n$"?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff edited.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your proof is true, you proofed that subgroup $H$ of group $\langle a \rangle$ is always $\{a^i \mid 0 \le i < k\}$, for some $k$. **That's False.**
2. The induction is false, I don't finally understand the try, but if you add an element $x$ to group $H$, and not add $x^{-1}$, $H \cup \{x\}$ is not a group.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do induction in that way. Why should $H=\{g^i:0\le i<k\}$?

The cleanest proof exploits the knowledge of the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ and the homomorphism theorems.

1. If $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ (with respect to addition, of course), then $H=n\mathbb{Z}$ for a unique integer $n\ge0$.
2. If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then the subgroups of $G/N$ are exactly those of the form $H/N$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $N$.

Now, with this knowledge, consider a cyclic group $G$; then there is a surjective homomorphism $\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$, so its kernel $\ker\varphi=n\mathbb{Z}$ for a unique $n\ge0$.

Therefore, we can reduce to the case where $G=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

A subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $H/n\mathbb{Z}$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $n\mathbb{Z}$; thus $H=m\mathbb{Z}$ where $m$ divides $n$. Since $m\mathbb{Z}$ is obviously cyclic, also its quotient $m\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic.

Comment: This is the only right way to put it (the part of the argument that uses Bezout's identity is then hidden in the classification of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$, where it belongs).

Comment: @RyanReich I've always found that reusing that argument several times is conceptually and didactically bad. The order of an element *is* the number of elements of the cyclic subgroup it generates. Then the fact it is the minimal positive exponent such that the power is the identity becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

We consider the surjective homomorphism $\pi : \mathbf{Z} \rightarrow \mathbf{{Z}/{nZ}}$.

Let $H$ a subgroup of $\mathbf{{Z}/{nZ}}$, by applying the homomorphism $\pi^{-1}(H)$ we obtain by properties of homomorphism a subgroup of $(\mathbf{Z},+)$.

However, we know that the subgroups of $(\mathbf{Z},+)$ are exactly the $n\mathbf{Z}$ which contain one generator. They are cyclic !

No we apply the homomorphism $\pi(\pi^{-1}(H))$. Hence, we obtain a subgroup of $(\mathbf{Z/nZ},+)$ this time. By properties of homomorphism $H$ is cyclic.