# Are idempotents always central in a von Neumann regular ring?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

A ring $R$ is called von Neumann regular if for every $a \in R$; $a=axa$ for some $x \in R$.

A ring $R$ called Abelian if every idempotent in $R$ is central.

Are [von Neumann regular rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring) abelian?

Comment: The endomorphism ring of a vector space over a division ring is an example of a non-commutative von Neumann regular ring: https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/von-neumann-regualr-rings-1/

Comment: @BenGrossmann It would appear that abelian may be used for rings, but only to say that the rings idempotents are central: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820235/why-are-groups-abelian-but-rings-commutative

Comment: @Ben Grossman: The post said what "abelian" meant; you are incorrect here.

Comment: Matrix algebras over fields are vNR but you can surely find non central idempotents no?

Answer (score 3):

$M_2(F)$ is von Neumann regular (for any field $F$), but has the noncentral idempotent $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

In fact it is known that a von Neumann regular ring is abelian if and only if it is *strongly regular*, meaning that for every $a\in R$ there exists a $b\in R$ such that $a^2b=a$.  Strongly regular rings do not have nonzero nilpotent elements, so you can see why the matrix ring example suggests itself as a counterexample.